# A question on $\mathbb{P}^1$-fibration

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have a simple question on algebraic surface theory. If the Kodaira dimension of $S$ is $-\infty$, then $S$ is a $\mathbb{P}^1$-bundle over a curve, and if the Kodaira dimension of $S$ is $1$, then $S$ is an elliptic surface. It seems to me that the fibers are always smooth in the former case and there may be singular fibers in the latter case. Now I suspect that more generally any $\mathbb{P}^1$-fibration over any variety is a smooth fibration. Is this true?

Comment: In the usual definition of a projective bundle (i.e. Proj of a locally free and finite rank sheaf on the base scheme), the morphism is automatically smooth. What do you call a $\mathbb P^1$-bundle ?

Comment: Yes, "bundle" means a smooth fibration. I am asking whether there is a $\mathbb{P}^1$-fibration or not. All $\mathbb{P}^1$-fibration I know are $\mathbb{P}^1$-bundles.

Comment: I can give you an example of a "$\mathbb{P}^1$-fibration which is not a $\mathbb{P}^1$-bundle" (i.e. a smooth surface $S$ together with a proper map $S\to C$ such that all fibers $S_c$ are isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^1$, yet it is not Zariski locally trivial). This isn't quite what you ask for though, because all fibers are smooth.

Comment: @Ronagh, welcome to MSE Pooya ;)

Comment: Dear @Matt, could you please give that  example ?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Actually, now that I go to write it down, I realized the standard example is not fibered over a curve, but over an open subset of $\mathbb{A}^2$. I'll have to think if it can be modified in any obvious way ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't true that a surface $S$ of Kodaira dimension $-\infty$ is a $P^1$-fibration over a curve, smooth fibres or not; the simplest example is $P^2$, which doesn't have *any* nontrivial maps to other varieties. What is true is that $S$ is birational to such a surface.

About your question: there are certainly fibre spaces whose general fibre is $P^1$, but which have singular fibres. An easy way to get one is to start with a $P^1$-bundle, and blow up a point. You can also try searching for "conic bundle" to see more interesting examples.

Comment: You are right. I was a bit confused.

Comment: I just cannot imagine how $\mathbb{P}^1$ degenerates to any other curves, but it may degenerate to, for example, a union of two $\mathbb{P}^1$s.

Comment: Ronagh: think about a family of plane conics whose general member is a smooth conic (hence isomorphic to P^1) but which has a member which is a union of 2 lines.

Comment: Yes, that's the example I have in mind.

Comment: Ah, then you _can_ imagine it. :)

Comment: Oh my typo, I meant "I couldn't imagine...". Haha.